# UIView with transparent background flickers on presentation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-animation, transparent

I've got really simple view controller that does this in its init:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.65];
```

When the view is added as a subview of a view that's already on screen, it's background flickers black (ignores the alpha) and then back to the proper color (with alpha).  No flicker occurs when alpha is 0 (no surprise) or 1 (no surprise).  Note that I'm not touching the alpha or opacity properties on the view or layer as that would cause all the subviews to be transparent also.

Any thoughts on how to fix the flicker?

Comment: in which method are you writing the above code?

Comment: It's in init.  I stated that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the backgroundColor in your view controller's init, I would put that line of code in your view controller's `viewDidLoad:` method. That might fix the 'flickering'.

Comment: No go.  I could see how this would fix it if it was in a viewDidAppear, but init and viewDidLoad should happen before any rendering takes place.

Comment: So are you initializing your ViewController in a nib/storyboard and overriding the `init` method? Or are you initializing your ViewController and presenting it all in code?

Comment: Nope.  This is an old view controller done completely programmatically that I'm trying to restyle.